# Sow Game Objects Differently to multiple cameras in Unity3D

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Hello there Firends ,

I'm developing a Virtual Reality game in Unity3D. As in every VR game , i have 2 cameras for stereo rendering.
I want to show the same object in each camera having different color/contrast ratio> The effect is similar to the one shown in this image :

[image: this]

the grid in the center here is the same in each side but each camera is seeing it differently.i.e. its grey in the left and black in right (you will notice the black grid if you look closely)

here is another example :
[image: this]
<sub>(source: [wired.co.uk](http://cdni.wired.co.uk/620x413/d_f/diplopia.jpg))</sub>

How do i get this effect ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why would you want this? What does this try to achieve? Altering the object for one eye only will be confusing for the users brain and may break immersion, cause disorientation and nausea.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be for each object to contain two display models, and use the layer assignment and masking on the cameras so that each camera sees a different version.

Also there's the OnCameraPreRender function. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.OnPreRender.html
If you put this function in a script attached to a camera object, it will get called before that particular camera is rendered.